# Angular + Protractor + Bamboo

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, bamboo

Has anyone setup Protractor e2e tests on Bamboo CI?

I've been running my WebDriver tests locally from Grunt via the grunt-protractor-runner / grunt-protractor-webdriver projects. Protractor config is standard. Relevant Grunt config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    protractor: {
        options: {
            keepAlive: false,
            noColor: false
        },
        modules: {
            configFile: 'protractor.e2e.conf.js'
        }
    },
    protractor_webdriver: {
        modules: {
            options: {
                path: 'node_modules/protractor/bin/',
                command: 'webdriver-manager start'
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('e2e', [ 'protractor_webdriver', 'protractor' ]);
```

This works like a charm locally with a simple `grunt e2e`

Trying to get this working on Bamboo is less than effective. My tasks so far:

- Checkout repo source
- `npm install`
- `webdriver-manager update`
- `grunt e2e`

The log shows it starting up Selenium server, launching Firefox, then failing with the following error:

```
UnknownError: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
```

Comment: Judging by the answers this applies only to Linux. Maybe it should explicitly be stated as such.

Answer (score 1):

When running this from bamboo you should also install something like Xvfb this enables you to start a headless screen that can be used from the commandline.

after installing Xvfb you can start a new screen by running

```
Xvfb :97 -ac -screen 0 1600x1200x24
```

in you grunt config you can add a new task

```
env : {
  xvfb: {
        DISPLAY: ':97'
  }
}
```

You shoud connect the screen before starting protractor. this can be done with

```
grunt.registerTask('e2e', [ 'env:xvfb','protractor_webdriver', 'protractor' ]);
```

Comment: may you already have a display installed on the agent there is no need to install Xvfb. You can use DISPLAY:=0 like kamituel replied

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to Firefox being launched (by Bamboo) from the console outside of X environment.

You could try modyfing grunt command to tell it explicitely what the display is:

```
DISPLAY=:0 grunt e2e
```