# How to configure Bamboo to run protractor test cases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, bamboo

I am new to Bamboo CI tool. I want to run my protractor test case in Bamboo but I dont know to do the setup.

My test case run fine locally but I dont know how to do the conf in bamboo. 
My conf looks like this : 
[image]

Please find my log error :

```
bot@gerrit.it.here.com:29418/CommunityPlatform/testing/supplier-portal\nbamboo_capability_Agent_Name=Melocanna\nbamboo_capability_system_jdk_JDK_1_8=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle\nbamboo_capability_system_jdk_JDK_1_7=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75\n
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:19    start testing
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20    [09:40:20] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20    [09:40:20] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20    [09:40:20] E/direct - Error code: 135
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20    [09:40:20] E/direct - Error message: Could not find chromedriver at /media/ephemeral0/c9ed21ed82cd/build-dir/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.25
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20    [09:40:20] E/direct - Error: Could not find chromedriver at /media/ephemeral0/c9ed21ed82cd/build-dir/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.25
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20        at Direct.getNewDriver (/media/ephemeral0/c9ed21ed82cd/build-dir/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:65:27)
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20        at Runner.createBrowser (/media/ephemeral0/c9ed21ed82cd/build-dir/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:190:43)
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20        at /media/ephemeral0/c9ed21ed82cd/build-dir/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:264:30
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20        at _fulfilled (/media/ephemeral0/c9ed21ed82cd/build-dir/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20        at self.promiseDispatch.done (/media/ephemeral0/c9ed21ed82cd/build-dir/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/media/ephemeral0/c9ed21ed82cd/build-dir/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20        at /media/ephemeral0/c9ed21ed82cd/build-dir/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20        at runSingle (/media/ephemeral0/c9ed21ed82cd/build-dir/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20        at flush (/media/ephemeral0/c9ed21ed82cd/build-dir/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:436:9)
build   24-Nov-2016 09:40:20    [09:40:20] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
simple  24-Nov-2016 09:40:20    Failing task since return code of [/bin/sh /tmp/RDMPDEV-SUP-JOB1-76-ScriptBuildTask-8031634411667419963.sh] was 135 while expected 0
simple  24-Nov-2016 09:40:20    Finished task 'Run Protractor test' with result: Failed
```

I would be grateful if someone can help me out. Thanks

Comment: Do you perform a `webdriver-manager update` command before running the protractor stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message show that you need to install a webdriver to perform protractor test. `node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update` should install the latest webdriver into `./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver<VERSION>`. In your `protractor.conf` file set this path as value of the `chromeDriver` property.

Additionally, for a headless bamboo server you might need to start a [virtual frame buffer](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) and set a `DISPLAY` environment variable to enable your Browser to render the pages without display hardware. There is a good explanation in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356028/angular-protractor-bamboo?rq=1).